# Does measurability of cardinal $\kappa$ imply measurability of $2^\kappa$?

Tags: set-theory, measure-theory

A cardinal $\kappa$ is *real-valued measurable* if there is a $\kappa$-additive probability measure on $2^\kappa$ which vanishes on singletons. The existence of measurable $\kappa$ is independent of ZFC.

Question: if $\kappa$ is assumed to be real-valued measurable, does it necessarily follow that $2^\kappa$ is real-valued measurable?

Comment: No. In fact, this almost never holds - if $2^\kappa$ is greater than continuum and real-valued measurable, then [it is measurable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_cardinal#Real-valued_measurable), but measurables are strong limits. So $2^\kappa$ can be real-valued measurable only if it's continuum.

Comment: @Wojowu You should make that an answer.

Comment: Independent of ZFC... not exactly: the consistency of ZFC doesn't imply the consistency of of ZFC + there exists a measurable cardinal, if I remember correctly. (But it implies the consistency of ZFC + there's no measurable cardinal.)

Comment: FYI: there is an older definition of "real-valued measurable" that only requires the probability measure to be countably additive. In that case, if one cardinal is rvm then so are all larger cardinals. This version of rvm is more common in earlier literature but one needs to be careful.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais Could you give a reference? If you turn into a full answer I'll be happy to accept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this is not necessarily true. In fact, this is almost never true - it can hold only if $2^\kappa$ is equal to the continuum.

Indeed, assume $2^\kappa$ is strictly greater than the continuum. By standard results (see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_cardinal#Real-valued_measurable)), a cardinal greater than continuum is real-valued measurable iff it's measurable. But measurable cardinals are necessarily strong limits, and $2^\kappa$ is, quite blatantly, not one.

Comment: On the other hand, it is consistent to have $\kappa<2^\kappa=\mathfrak c$, both of them real-valued measurable.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Do you get this by starting with two measurable cardinals $\kappa<\lambda$ and adding $\lambda$ random reals? Or is something trickier involved?

Comment: @Andreas Yes, that's all that's needed.

Comment: @Andrés: And there I was, thinking that all you need is love! I'd be interested in hearing *that* rendition, "All you need is two measurable cardinals (and a lot of random reals)".